# GPS metadata null on Cordova-plugin-camera-with-exif

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-camera

Using version **1.5.1** of [Cordova-plugin-camera-with-exif](https://github.com/remoorejr/cordova-plugin-camera-with-exif) and quasar 3 typescript based , when extracting exif data from image captured with cordova, , i'm able to get some of the metadata, but not the gps.

```
{ "aperture": "2.0", "datetime": "2022:10:27 01:41:55", "exposureTime": "0.120003", "flash": "0", "focalLength": "3500/1000", "gpsAltitude": null, "gpsAltitudeRef": null, "gpsDateStamp": null, "gpsLatitude": null, "gpsLatitudeRef": null, "gpsLongitude": null, "gpsLongitudeRef": null, "gpsProcessingMethod": null, "gpsTimestamp": null, "iso": "807", "make": "motorola", "model": "moto g pro", "orientation": "0", "whiteBalance": "0" }
```

**Cordova & Cordova android > 10.1.1**

**PS**: Gps is enabled on my device.

Here is my configuration :

```
  quality: 30,
  
  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  
  encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  
  sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA ,
  
  mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
  
  cameraDirection: Camera.Direction.BACK,
  
  correctOrientation: true
```

I'm I missing something ?

Comment: iOS or Android ?

Comment: @Eric same for both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android, we need to activate save location feature in the camera settings itself.
To resume, there is 2 permissions.

- one for the app itself (geolocation permission)
- one from camera settings => save location

more infos : https://support.google.com/photos/answer/9921876#zippy=%2Chtc-devices%2Cmotorola-devices%2Cios-devices